# Running programs, saving results

Tags: usb, software-installation

If I'm using Pi 3B+ to learn SQL and Python and doing exercises, should I install programs on an external USB drive because of limited size of Pi?

Comment: it is entirely up to you .... if you have space then you do not need to put programs on an external drive ........ however, you should always save your work at an external location as a backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because of limited size of Pi

You can get a 128 (or 256) GB SD card for about the same as you'd get a small external drive, which should be enough to hold all the python and SQL exercise data you can stomach and then some, so this is not really about "the limited size of the pi", it is about your preferences WRT storage.

Spinning disk drives are hard to get under 1/2 TB -- which realistically is way, way, way beyond what the use case you describe could reasonably require.  This means
USB sticks are probably the cheapest option.  But in all honesty, **16 or 32 GB** would still be more than enough, if learning python and SQL is what you are doing -- in fact, if that's all you are doing, **4 or 8 GB** should be fine.

So the simple and obvious thing to do would be to just start with a quality 16 GB card.

If after a while you find you are running out of room, you can get a stick and save stuff onto that.  You don't need to confine yourself to only one piece of media.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the size of the data you are working with, and the size of the SD card you are using for the Pi. You should check the available space in your card and evaluate if the program and data you will create will fill this space in a considerable time.